# Google Option Chain API - RJSON

Tags: json, r

I want to import in R the option chain json file that google provides in this link:

```
http://www.google.com/finance/option_chain?q=NASDAQ:GOOG&output=json
```

R read correctly the json raw data, but seem unable to correct decode the values.
Here's my code:

```
library(RJSONIO)
library(RCurl)
raw_data <- getURL("http://www.google.com/finance/option_chain?q=NASDAQ:GOOG&output=json")
data <- fromJSON(raw_data)
```

I've seen and tried all the others topic on the argument, nothing seems to work here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Google, in their infinite wisdom, does not enclose the key names in quotes, so the returned JSON in not well formed. You need to add the quotes back in.

```
library(RJSONIO)
library(RCurl)
raw_data <- getURL("http://www.google.com/finance/option_chain?q=NASDAQ:GOOG&output=json")
raw_data <- gsub("(\\w+)\\s*:",'"\\1":',raw_data)   # enclose keys in double quotes
data <- fromJSON(raw_data)
```

BTW: There is a `getOptionChain(...)` function in package `quantmod` that pulls this data from Yahoo Finance, but it does not always work. You should also be aware that Google has announced the discontinuance of their Finance API, so this will not necessarily work in the future.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, and for the suggestion regards **getOptionChain** , I've use it since last year, and lately it's become totally unreliable, that's why I'm looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

or even easier than above answer, if performance is not your concern: use demjson instead of json package, as it is fault tolerant.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/demjson/2.2.4